# Subset-selection using Pandas "isin"-syntax

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have a question regarding a table (Table A - containing multiple values of three keys and some "value" columns) according to below:

```
ID     TIME1       TIME2     VALUE_A      VALUE_B
1      201501      201501    a            1a
1      201502      201502    a            1c
1      201502      201502    b            1d 
1      201501      201501    b            2e
1      201501      201501    b            6a
1      201501      201501    b            1d 
1      201502      201502    b            2e
1      201502      201502    b            6a
```

I have used a code creating unique values from another table, getting a reference of the rows I want to extract from table A, given the keys. This table (table B) has the appearance according to below:

```
ID     TIME1        TIME2      
1      201502      201502    
2      201511      201511
```

I have manage to take out the values I want by doing a simple merge which gives the values I want from table A, given references. However, I would like to use the "isin"-function to make this happened also. I have my syntax according to below, and it gives me duplicate values. The only thing I want is to take out the rows from Table A, given reference from Table B. How can I gear it to do that?

Table C according to below:

```
ID     TIME1       TIME2     VALUE_A      VALUE_B
1      201502      201502    a            1c
1      201502      201502    b            1d 
1      201502      201502    b            2e
1      201502      201502    b            6a
```

Syntax("isin"-version):

```
subset = df[df.ID.isin(df2['ID']) & (df.TIME1.isin(df2['TIME1']) & df.TIME2.isin(df2['TIME2']))]
```

Code for creating table A and table B is below:

```
    df = DataFrame({'ID' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
               'TIME1' : [201501,201502,201502,201501,201501,201501,201502,201502],
               'TIME2' : [201501,201502,201502,201501,201501,201501,201502,201502],
               'VALUE_A' : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
               'VALUE_B' : ['1a', '1c', '1d', '2e', '6a', '1d', '2e', '6a']})


    df2 = DataFrame({'ID' : [1,2],
                'TIME1' : [201502,201501],
                'TIME2' : [201502,201501]
                })
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry your question is unclear to me, can you post what the desired result is, as far as I can tell your isin version gives the same result as `df.merge(df2)`

Comment: I have posted "table c" as an example of what I want to get out from using the "isin"-functionality!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to modify your boolean condition to this:

```
In [146]:
subset = df[df.ID.isin(df2['ID']) & (df.TIME1.isin(df2['TIME1']) | df.TIME2.isin(df2['TIME2'])) ]
subset

Out[146]:
   ID   TIME1   TIME2 VALUE_A VALUE_B
1   1  201502  201-02       a      1c
2   1  201502  201502       b      1d
6   2  201511  201511       b      2e
7   2  201511  201511       b      6a
```

So this checks that the ID is present and that either Time1 or Time2 is in the other df.

Comment: The strange thing is that when I apply this logic to a bigger table that im working on, I get a "True" for all boolean values, despite me having different "time"-columns and the same ID-number? Do you know if there are any cases where the boolean expression isnt evaluated over all three included colums, so it only looks on the first column ("id")

Comment: You'll have to define preferably with sample data, code and expected output as to what you want. At the moment I'm using your code and the desired output I think you need to fully explain what the True/False conditions are

Comment: I have changed the outlay of the input table slightly. Using the same logic, and sorry for being unclear, I would like to get out table C, i.e. all the rows that fulfill the condition of being in the reference table b.

Comment: You've not stated the conditions, please edit this into your question

Comment: I have edited the "isin"-function that im trying to use but it produced multiple rows on id = 1 and its adherent time stamps. I only want the first row in table B to be selected from table A, producing table C. I hope that clearly states what I want. Sorry for being un-clear!

Comment: OK I understand what you're after, you can't use `isin` like this because for your data set it returns the rows with values 201511 because this still satisfies the condition that ID is in [1,2] and Time1 and Time2 are also in those row values, you have to use merge to get row matches like you desire: `df.merge(df2)`

Comment: Ok, that settles it! Thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 2):

simply you can achieve this using `isin()` by

```
In [102]:
df[df.TIME1.isin(df2.TIME1) & df.TIME2.isin(df2.TIME2)]

Out[102]:
ID  TIME1   TIME2   VALUE_A VALUE_B
1   201502  201502     a    1c
1   201502  201502     b    1d
2   201511  201511     b    2e
2   201511  201511     b    6a
```